# Regx to match text before numbers and special characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a pack of texts say :

- Suitcase 6l
- Backpack (28kg)
- Duffel Bag 6kg
- Purse [3kg]
- Duffel Bag [25l]
- Duffel Bag 10l

I want to only extract the type of bags **before the number, space, and any special characters** like [ or (, like:

- Suitecase
- Backpack
- Duffel Bag
- Purse

I tried to use to match the nondigit characters with case insensitive, but I don't know how to exclude the special characters and space.

```
(?i)(\D*^)
```

Can someone help me how to do it using regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match the different listed formats `l` and `kg` with or without the `()` and `[]` and capture the type of bags in a group.

For a case insensitive match, you can prepend the regex with `(?i)` or in Python use the `re.I` flag.

```
^([A-Z].*?)\s+(?:\[\d+(?:l|kg)]|\(\d+(?:l|kg)\)|\d+(?:l|kg)\b)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([A-Z].*?)` Start the match with a char A-Z and then match as few as possible chars
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\[\d+(?:l|kg)]` Match 1+ digits and either `l` or `kg` between `[...]`
  - `|` Or
  - `\(\d+(?:l|kg)\)` The same between `(...)`
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+(?:l|kg)\b` Match 1+ digits and either `l` or `kg`
- `)` Close the non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VZlTgQ/1)

Answer (score 0):

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/mGSRC7/1) will get you pretty close, with just the possibility of some extra spaces captured which you could get rid of with `trim()`:

`\b[a-zA-Z ]+\b`

This basically says to find the largest group of letters and spaces that don't contain any numbers or special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be what you're looking for

```
[[:alpha:]]+(\s[[:alpha:]]+)?(?!\S*\n)
```

`[[:alpha:]]+` matches any group of letters 
`(\s[[:alpha:]]+)?` optionally matches a white space and a group of letters 
`(?!\S*\n)` this is a negative lookahead, if looking forward there is an optional group of non whitespaces followed by a new line then the match will be discarded.